# Duende IdentityServer 5.0 - Sign in user after SAML Authentication (from Users IDP)

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2, duende-identity-server

We have :
Our own IDP --> Duende Identity  Server (5.0)

MVC Client that users log into after they are authenticated by our IDP (above)

External Client that wants to have SSO to our MVC Client so will send is a SAML Assertion (IDP initiated SAML ) we user ITfoxtec as a SAML processing library

Once we verify and validate the SAML Assertion and the user, how do we sign in the user to our IDP (Duende Identity Server)

```
context.SignInAsync(new IdentityServerUser, Auth props);
```

will this create a new Token and session for the external client user on our IDP
If we re-direct the new user to our MVC application will it be able to tell that the user is indeed Authenticated.

Do we need to specify an Authentication scheme when signing in the user to our Duende IDP ?

```
context.SignInAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, IdentityServerUser user);
```

Is this correct?
One key requirement is we need to have an Access token that the MVC Client App used for many other needs (Access to other features)